# QML mobile app with context menus

Tags: android, ios, qt, contextmenu, qml

I want to create a mobile app (with possible desktop use) that uses a context menu and has as close to a native look and feel as possible for both Android and iOS. (This is my first foray into both Qt and QML.)

I figured out how to create a `Menu` and call `myMenu.popup()` to show the context menu. And in Android this context menu looks very similar to a native android context menu. This context menu also looks native on the desktop. The problem comes with iOS.

iOS has a similar concept to context menus called actionsheets. [Examples.](https://www.google.com/search?q=uiactionsheet&tbm=isch) But the contextMenu looks like a windows context menu (right click menu) floating on the window.

**tl;dr;**

Is there a way to get the `Menu` in qml to look similar to iOS actionsheets when run on a iOS device? I have searched for hours today and can't find anything.

**code:**

The `Menu` code is mostly copied from the Qt docs just to see how things look and work

```
Menu
{
    id: myContextMenu
    title: "Edit"

        MenuItem {
            text: "Cut"
            onTriggered: {console.log("cut")}
        }

        MenuItem {
            text: "Copy"
            onTriggered: {console.log("copy")}
        }

        MenuItem {
            text: "Paste"
            onTriggered: {console.log("paste")}
        }

        MenuSeparator { }

        Menu {
            title: "More Stuff"

            MenuItem {
                text: "Do Nothing"
            }
        }
}
MouseArea {
      id: longPressArea
      anchors.fill: text
      onClicked: {
          myContextMenu.popup()
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the comments above: No, not in the current version of Qt, unless you roll your own in QML.

Quick Controls uses one of [native, QWidget, QML] implementations, whichever is found first.  You can read the source to see that there is no native implementation: grep for createPlatformMenu() in Qt/../Src/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/ios.  Thats where the adaptors to native widgets are.

Another answer is: you could contribute by creating the adaptor to the native widget for iOS (if you are an iOS and C++ programmer.)  Also assuming that a UIActionSheet is the proper widget to adapt (it seems so.)

I suppose your concern is that a centered menu (instead of a native one that animatedly slides onto the screen like a drawer, the feel) doesn't meet the HIG (or that the style/look is wrong.)  Thats a moving target.  The [iOS8 documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html) under showInView seems to say a centered popup menu is an option (at least on iPad, its unclear whether it would work on a phone.) And its fuzzy what the store would reject.

Isn't that an intended benefit of QML: you could provide different skins for tablet and phone?

Comment: My concern wasn't necessarily an HIG violation, but more of an attempt to make an application that looked "native" on each device. Instead of an app that successfully runs on iOS but looks and acts differently from established iOS apps

Comment: In the end I went with an approach that avoided using context menus completely, but I marked this as the answer since it does answer the original question and provide a means to create what I was asking for.

Comment: I ended up designing the GUI around not needing context menus. Similar to how the facebook app works where you have individual buttons to provide context menu like functionality on each item

Comment: I found that QuickControls1.2:Menu doesn't show in Qt5.3.2 (a bug?) but that in Qt5.4beta Controls1.3:Menu appears at the bottom with Cancel and Done buttons at its top, but it seems to take a fixed portion of the screen (on iPad) and scrolls.  Not sure what native widget that is.

Answer (score 0):

With Qt Labs, since Qt5.8, you can get native looking menus on macOS, iOS, Android and Linux (gtk+). Haven't tried it myself yet, but you can take a look:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-qt-labs-platform-menu.html

You need to `import Qt.labs.platform 1.1`, link against widgets with `QT += widgets` and use a `QApplication` instead of `QGuiApplication`.

For comparison, here is also the stable menu from qml which does not try to look native. 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html